# An injected link to the website flagged up by google seach console

Tags: wordpress, security, google-search-console

I got an email this morning from google search console about **'Social Engineering Content Detected on Your Site'** and they link the sent is something like this  `http://****.co[.]uk/~bettingb/`

The website is **WordPress** website and I searched for the link in my files and database and I only found it in wordfence table `wp_wfHits`.

Is it possible that google crawled that link from this table?

is this something serious?

Any advice?

Comment: Googlebot doesn't crawl your database.  It crawls your website; which delivers content, in part, from your database.  If the table is created by Wordfence, then its content is probably not forward facing at all.  TeeJayEss has a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before you act upon cjmling's advice, wp_wfHits is a legitimate table created by Wordfence (a security plugin).

[As shown here](https://www.wordfence.com/help/advanced/remove-or-reset/)

The fact that it is in this table means that Wordfence has noticed it, which is exactly what you want. I cannot imagine that this is the only place in the database that has this but it may be encoded elsewhere.

The other thing is that Wordfence may have already cleaned up the issue between Google spotting it and you looking into it. I would let Search Console run again and see if it is found again.

DO NOT think that your site has been fully compromised, change any admin passwords but you'll probably find that it was stuff added as a comment to a post (usual WordPress "hack")

Also, if you really want to be secure, change the database prefix (Wordfence I think has this option out the box) which means you are then not using the standard "wp_" prefix and you can spot things easier!

Comment: I would have a look at the latest scan results which will tell you what, if any, action was taken against anything it found on the scan.

https://www.wordfence.com/help/scan/scan-results/

Comment: This is cool. That table naming (mixed cap/lower) looks liked hacked naming I often experienced. My bad to judge too quickly. Deleted my comments.

Comment: No problems @cjmling, just be aware that just because you don't recognise a table it may not be a hack. Developers can and will lose sleep over the word "hack" but in this instance, I think the system has worked

Comment: I did the scan and nothing critical just yellow warning about plugin updates.

Comment: Well, that looks good. You should have a look at past scans and double check what action was taken on them too.

Comment: Oh and get those plugins updated, something that @cjmling did mention was correct, keeping plugins updated is an important part of WordPress security. Publishers often give updates to remove vulnerabilities so always keep WP AND all plugins up-to-date